# Consecutively close divs on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and jQuery and have no idea where to start with this, or if it's possible. However, I have three 'floating' divs on screen that I want to be able to remove (display:none) one by one, by clicking anywhere on the body. Any help is appreciated!

This is the code for one of the 'floating' divs (all three have the same format, just different ID's).

```
<div id="yellow-draggable" class="div">
    <div class="arrow">
        <img class="white-arrow-yellow" src="img/whiteArrow.svg">
    </div>
    <a href="sections/dr.html">
        <div class="box yellow yellow-box">
            <p class="hover-title">Disaster Recovery</p>
            <p class="hover-copy hover-yellow">43% of businesses have tested their disaster recovery plan in the last year.</p>
            <a class="hover-link" href="sections/dr.html">See the full Disaster Recovery results</a> 
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="graph">
        <img src="img/graphFiveDR.svg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It most certainly is possible but you should try it on your own. But here's a hint.  If they all have the same class, make an event listener for that class, then get id of the first one it finds (in order of loading in the DOM) and add a css property of `display:none`

I'll leave it to you to puzzle out the details but come back and ask a more specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: Do all `div`s have a common attribute (class for instance)?

Comment: @Y2H They don't currently have a common class, but this could be easily added

Comment: I was gonna give you an answer based on that but I see other people have answered already. If you still need help let me know though. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

```js
// this is listen for click event of full body
$("body").on("click", function() {
  // This will hide first visible div on click of body. Let's add animation while hiding so pass face out time.
  $('.div:visible').first().hide(200);

})
```

```css
.div{
width: 50%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yellow-draggable1" class="div">
  <div class="arrow">
    <img class="white-arrow-yellow" src="img/whiteArrow.svg">
  </div>
  <a href="sections/dr.html">
    <div class="box yellow yellow-box">
      <p class="hover-title">Disaster1 Recovery</p>
      <p class="hover-copy hover-yellow">3% of businesses have tested their disaster recovery plan in the last year.</p>
      <a class="hover-link" href="sections/dr.html">See the full Disaster Recovery results</a>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="graph">
    <img src="img/graphFiveDR.svg">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="yellow-draggable2" class="div">
  <div class="arrow">
    <img class="white-arrow-yellow" src="img/whiteArrow.svg">
  </div>
  <a href="sections/dr.html">
    <div class="box yellow yellow-box">
      <p class="hover-title">Disaster2 Recovery</p>
      <p class="hover-copy hover-yellow">4% of businesses have tested their disaster recovery plan in the last year.</p>
      <a class="hover-link" href="sections/dr.html">See the full Disaster Recovery results</a>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="graph">
    <img src="img/graphFiveDR.svg">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="yellow-draggable3" class="div">
  <div class="arrow">
    <img class="white-arrow-yellow" src="img/whiteArrow.svg">
  </div>
  <a href="sections/dr.html">
    <div class="box yellow yellow-box">
      <p class="hover-title">Disaster3 Recovery</p>
      <p class="hover-copy hover-yellow">5% of businesses have tested their disaster recovery plan in the last year.</p>
      <a class="hover-link" href="sections/dr.html">See the full Disaster Recovery results</a>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="graph">
    <img src="img/graphFiveDR.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but I want the user to be able to click the page body to close the elements one by one, not the divs themselves

Comment: @JessCauchi So how user select which div they want to close? from list?

Comment: It doesn't matter what order they close, it can be randomised

Comment: @JessCauchi Check updated ans. Just add click listener on "body" and get first visible ".div" and hide it.

Comment: @JessCauchi If this answer helps you, mark as a answer by clicking correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if it is always the same case you have, you could just have a counter.

```
let counter = 0;

$('body').on('click', function() {
  switch(counter) {
    case 1:
      // set style display none on second div
      break;
    case 2:
      // set style display none on third div
      break;
    default:
       // set style display none on first div
  }
}
```

I havn't tested the code, but you should be able to do something like that.
Or use the the $('taget').hide() function as mentioned by Rémi.M.

Comment: Thank you, however I tried this and found that it only closed the first div then didn't do anything after.

Comment: JessCauchi, you will have to taget the individual divs in the individual cases.
`$("#divone").attr("css", "display: none;")` in one case
`$("#divtwo").attr("css", "display: none;")` in another case

Answer (score 0):

i tested it and work fine :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').click(function(e){
$('.arrow').hide(200);
$('.box').hide(200);
$('.graph').hide(200);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest one-line solution to hide one div per-click. Click anywhere on the body.

Search the `first` `visible` `.box` and `hide` it.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'body', function() {
  $('div.box:visible:first').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="yellow-draggable" class="div">
    <div class="arrow">
      <img class="white-arrow-yellow" src="img/whiteArrow.svg">
    </div>
    <a href="sections/dr.html">
      <div class="box yellow yellow-box">
        <p class="hover-title">Disaster Recovery</p>
        <p class="hover-copy hover-yellow">43% of businesses have tested their disaster recovery plan in the last year.</p>
        <a class="hover-link" href="sections/dr.html">See the full Disaster Recovery results</a>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="sections/dr.html">
      <div class="box yellow yellow-box">
        <p class="hover-title">Disaster Recovery</p>
        <p class="hover-copy hover-yellow">43% of businesses have tested their disaster recovery plan in the last year.</p>
        <a class="hover-link" href="sections/dr.html">See the full Disaster Recovery results</a>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="sections/dr.html">
      <div class="box yellow yellow-box">
        <p class="hover-title">Disaster Recovery</p>
        <p class="hover-copy hover-yellow">43% of businesses have tested their disaster recovery plan in the last year.</p>
        <a class="hover-link" href="sections/dr.html">See the full Disaster Recovery results</a>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="graph">
      <img src="img/graphFiveDR.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple demo for you please check with snippet

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e){
 var $div = $('div');
  var index = 0;
  var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(index < $div.length) {
      $div.eq(index++).hide(600);
    } else {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.one {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: #00A321;
   margin: 15px;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this also -

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('body').on('click','div',function()
     {
          if($(this).attr('id') =='yellowdraggable')
          $(this).attr('style','display: none');
          event.preventDefault();
     })
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply hide the divs by using hide() method also.

```
$('body').click(function() {
   $('#yellow-draggable').hide();
});
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't what I'm looking for. This will just close one div. I need to be able to click on the body and close three different divs one after another.

Comment: yup I've got your question, this was just a way to hide a div, in your case you can take a counter for click and increase counter each time when you click on body as well as hide div one by one.

Comment: something like this -  


    var counter = 0;
    $(document).click(function(e) { 
      if(counter == 0) {
        $('#div1').hide()
        counter += 1 
       }else if(counter == 1) {
        $('#div2').hide()
        counter += 1
       } else {
        $('#div3').hide()
       }
    });